# How to connect BitBucket Server on Azure VM with Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-networking, bitbucket, azure-devops

I have a Azure VM with BitBucket Server Installed. How do I connect this  to Azure DevOps for establishing a CI-CD pipeline ?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to expose your IaaS VM instance externally by way of a PIP (don't forget to lock it down with an NSG) to allow Azure Pipelines to connect to it. In Azure Pipelines, you can select "Other GIT" where you can enter the URL and credentials of the generic Git service connection. Ensure you allow public access to the repo, [see Atlassian doco](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/allowing-public-access-to-code-776639799.html).